# How to change the cursor on a Button?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, user-interface, button

```
static HWND btn;
HCURSOR cursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_CROSS);

case WM_CREATE:
    btn = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Press Me"),
                       WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE, 50, 50, 80, 30,
                       hwnd, (HMENU) 111, NULL, NULL);
```

Now, in `WM_COMMAND`, I try to use:

```
SendMessage(btn, WM_SETCURSOR, 0, (LPARAM) cursor);
```

Which isn't working.

So how do I change the cursor of the mouse after it clicks the button? Also, how do I change the cursor of the mouse as it is hovering over the button (like it changes to a hand when hovering over links in web-browsers)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code to change the cursor of a single control:

```
SetClassLong(btn, GCL_HCURSOR, (LONG)cursor);
```

Preferred method, for 64 bit compatibility, is:

```
SetClassLongPtr(btn, GCL_HCURSOR, (LONG_PTR)cursor);
```

Note that this won't change the icon only for the specified `btn` window but for all windows with the same class, you have to first register a custom class name with `RegisterClass()` and then use it in the `WNDCLASS.lpszClassName` structure when creating `btn`.

Again this will apply to all the Windows with that (custom) class. To change the cursor of a single specific window you need to subclass it, manage the `WM_SETCURSOR` message and if (for example) `lParam` is `HTCLIENT` (pointer entered the window client area) then call `SetCursor()` to set the cursor you want (don't forget to return `TRUE` in this case). Of course this might be temporary (calling `SetWindowLongPtr()` with `GWLP_WNDPROC`).

Comment: Thanks. But according to MSDN, isn't it better to use `SetClassLongPtr` instead?

Comment: @IntermediateHacker yes, for easy compatibility with 64 bit.

Comment: Erm, whatever happened to [not using global scope to fix a local problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx)? `SetClassLong` will change the cursor for EVERY control created from the same class (in the same process I think).

Comment: @Deanna so true!!! Edited the answer to use the right function (I even wrote 'for a single control' lol)

Comment: @ajay your issue may be different, if you need a solution it's better you post a new question describing your problem, your actual solution and the issue you have!

Comment: SetClassPtr() is changing cursor for all controls, belonging to a class, (i.e. for all buttons is dialog), not for a particular button.

Comment: @ajay yes, that's why we suggested SetWindowLongPtr

Comment: @Adriano, SetWindowLongPtr() is not changing the cursor sir, and also MSDN shows no constant for that.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898(v=vs.85).aspx SetClassLongPtr() also changes cursor for all similar controls.

Also using SetWindowLongPtr() blocks other functionality implemented on that particular button whose handle is passed as 1st parameter.

Comment: That's why they work on the same structure (indices are an offset from struct address inside a bigger structure), for SetWindowLong **only some of them are documented** but they point to same memory. What's different is how HWND is interpreted by that functions. Take a look too WNDCLASS structure too...

Comment: x64 note: GCLP_HCURSOR, not GCL_HCURSOR

Comment: SetWindowLongPtr() cannot be called with GCL_HCURSOR (GCL stands for GetClassLong). The answer is wrong, it does not work!

Comment: @DanielMarschall you're right, original answer was with `SetClassLong()`, I changed the called function without changing the given constant! Good catch after so many years!

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`SetCursor()` in the `WM_SETCURSOR` message handler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/25/421707.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

```
LRESULT CALLBACK DlgProc (HWND hWndDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
   static RECT rcButton;
   static HWND hButton;
   static HCURSOR hCursor;
   // ...
  switch (message) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
      hButton = GetDlgItem (hWndDlg, IDC_BUTTON);
      GetClientRect (hButton, &rcButton);
      MapWindowPoints (hButton, hWndDlg, (LPPOINT) &rcButton, 2);
      break;
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
      if ((LOWORD (lParam) >= rcButton.left - 1 && LOWORD (lParam) <= rcButton.right) && (HIWORD (lParam) >= rcButton.Top - 1 && (HIWORD (lParam) <= rcButton.bottom))
          SetClassLong (hButton, GCL_HCURSOR, (LONG) LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_CROSS));
      else
         SetClassLong (hButton, GCL_HCURSOR, (LONG) LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW));
      break;
   // ...
```

it will do your work for sure!

Answer (score 1):

> Also, how do I change the cursor of the mouse as it is hovering over
>   the button (like it changes to a hand when hovering over links in
>   web-browsers)?

You could superclass the button and create a new class of buttons that have the hand icon.

Use GetClassInfoEx on the BUTTON class, change the cursor, give it a new class name, register it and use the new class name to create the button with CreateWindowEx.